# answer yes's to repeated unix prompts

Tags: unix, pip, pipe

I'm trying to run `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` in terminal, and I have to type `y` multiple times.

For example:

```
Uninstalling arrow-0.12.0:
  Would remove:
    /Users/catherine/anaconda3/envs/analysis_pipeline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arrow-0.12.0.dist-info/*
    /Users/catherine/anaconda3/envs/analysis_pipeline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arrow/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

Is there a way that I can pass `y`s repeatedly? In this situation it doesn't really matter, but I'd love to have a more generalizable solution for similar cases.

I've tried googling and using the `|` operator but both did not work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @jubobs, my read on the question was that it was asking for this but more generally a way to pass args to a CLI that will be parsed in order. I'd be more interested in that question personally. Thanks for link tho!

edit: andddd that's there. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterDolan Let's see whether the OP is satisfied with the answers to the other question. We can always reopen this one, if needed.